# Default image not loading

Tags: database, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, backend

The image in my Flask app has not been loading, when I view the page source it shows src="/static/profile_pics/c1a7ec356936a3db.jpg", when I changed it to src="/static/profile_pics/default.jpg", it showed the image , then I tried querying my database then realized that the default image is c1a7ec356936a3db.jpg instead of default.jpg

```
>>> from flaskblog.models import User
>>> user = User.query.first()
>>> user
User('fortunenwankwo_','therealfortune1@gmail.com','c1a7ec356936a3db.jpg')
```

this is my models.User file

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    image_file = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, default='default.jpg')
    password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref="author", lazy=True)
```

this is my account route file

```
@app.route("/account", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def account():
    image_file = url_for('static', filename='profile_pics/' + current_user.image_file)
    return render_template("account.html", title="Account", image_file=image_file, form=form)
```

The main question is how can I change my default image to default.jpg instead of c1a7ec356936a3db.jpg, is it possible for me to change it by querying my models file in the terminal?

ok so I realized it was just for that user , so please how can I change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I discovered that the problem was just one account , I deleted the account